# Why do we need two dimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Why do we need two-dimensional or multi-dimensional array?

If we want a series of continuous elements of the same type, it can be achieved with simple 1-D array. Like `int[] a = new int[15625]` will allocate space 15625 elements, and
`int [][][] b = new int[25][25][25]` will also allocate space 15625 elements

Why do we need them if things can be achieved with 1-d?

Comment: this is same as saying why do we need array when we have normal single variable

Comment: @singhakash: Not quite; you cannot simulate an array with a variable.

Comment: Note that Java doesn't really have multi-dimensional arrays. They are nested arrays.

Comment: Also, why have strings when you can use char arrays? why have classes when you can just keep everything in a group of parallel arrays? why have functions when you can just write the same block of code multiple times?

Comment: @singhakash we need array for multiple places to put large no of same type of elements at continuous places in memory which can't be achieved  with variable, and if you do so with variable to put it will be cumbersome and really a headache for developer to handle 15625 values with variables. SO that why we need arrays there are other countless reasons too,

Comment: @khelwood I like the way you point out the OOPS's abstraction concept in your comment but multidimensional array do not provide the things that you wrote in your comment, it is simple to have single array and iterate it when require rather than having multi-d arrays that will do same, but in contrast we need more loops for multidimensional arrays to get values back from it, but 1-D requires only 1 loop to do the operations on it.

Comment: @PankajSharma this is what I am saying you need 2d array becase you need to store same type of data like storing diffrent subject marks of different student one row in 2d array will represent student and one column for each subject we can store that 2d data to 1d but it would not be a clean approach  and if you do so with 1d array handling it will be cumbersome and really a headache for developer to handle.

Comment: @SinghAkash I agree what you are saying , and I follow you on your views completely, but do you think only it was clean so computer languages add multi-dimensional array feature in them. there must be a strong and technical reason behind the scene, I am looking for that reason

Comment: Java doesn't have multidimensional arrays,  int[][] is not a 2D array but an array of int[].  While you can use them in a similar manner, there are some distinct differences.  See my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need them, but doing `grid[x][y]` is nicer than `grid[x + y*width]`

Comment: thanks for replying, but the question still stands, what do we get by doing this, the same thing we can achieve by grid[x*y] and accessing them by index where we require them, performance wise, memory wise they are exactly same, so there must be some other solid reason to have multi-diamensional array that java included them, not only because they are nice.

Comment: @PankajSharma, they aren't the same performance-wise or memory-wise, and one of the historical lessons of software development is that ease of understanding for developers is probably even _more_ valuable than performance.

Comment: @Louis thanks for sparing your time, you are right memory-wise and performance-wise multi-d's are not equal to 1-d's they even occupy more space than 1-d's because of object header at every level of nested arrays to hold the references for its next rows, and they also operations on multi-dimensional array's require more logic like more loops to extract the information from them, but with 1-d's this not the case, they are easy on both these aspects,

Comment: @PankajSharma If you have a gameboard of size 10 by 10, saying `board[x][y]` is considerably easier to understand than `board[10*x + y]`.  We _think_ in terms of multiple dimensions.  (And having more `for` loops can make things _easier_ to understand if they match how humans think about the logic in the first place.)

Comment: thanks Louis, it clarified me....!

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes data isn't one dimensional.

For example, the classic game breakout. You could organize your bricks into a one dimensional array and each turn process which row they are in, however it makes more sense to make it a two-dimensional array where the first array is the rows, and the second array is the bricks.

i.e:

bricks[0][3] is the fourth brick of the rirst row

While this could still be done with a one dimensional array, there are math applications where multi-dimensional arrays are necessary.

In addition to this it allows you to have arrays of an infinite<sup>1.</sup> size, whereas arrays are limited to 2<sup>30</sup>

<sup>1. mileage may vary</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, multi-dimensional arrays in Java are actually nested arrays.  Your nested arrays don't all need to be the same size which is one reason you would use them instead of a single array as you have proposed.

The only other way to declare such an array (off the top of my head) is to declare an array of type Object and then put arrays in it but you lose the basic array type safety.  You can access the elements in nested arrays without the [][]... syntax, however.